# JQuery delete button not working

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I have a JQuery function which creates a popup dialog box, which you have to click to continue, however whilst the box pops up and everything works fine the link doesn't trigger the php link.

Below is the JQuery code:.

```
jQuery('.delete-row').click(function () {
    var conf = confirm('Continue delete?');
    if (conf) jQuery(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(function () {
       jQuery(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

And here is my code which calls the dialog box and should pass the php info to the block.php page:

```
 echo "<a href=\"block.php?ip_address={$ip_address}&id={$id}&userna={$username1}\" class='delete-row' data-original-title='Delete'>Block</a>";
```

Comment: I assume "j Query" is a typo?

Comment: @DerekHenderson you should have posted this as an answer, might just solve the issue :)

Comment: @lazyprogrammer, he said everything works except for the link, so I have to assume it was just a typo typing it into SO and that he got that bit right in his code.

Comment: I know it's a typo but I find the `j Query` including the capital but having an extra space to be hilarious. Maybe I've been programming too long?

Comment: Sorry, don't what happened there but it is just a type

Comment: @user1691024, what do you mean by "the link doesn't trigger the php link"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function () {
    var conf = confirm('Continue delete?');
    if (conf){ jQuery(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(function () {
            jQuery(this).remove();
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it made no difference

Comment: have u any testing link for debug ?

Comment: The problem seems to be the "return false;" here, as @Herode pointed out it should be "else return false;"

Comment: Why did you accept this answer and not Herodes, since he proposed the correct answer and this one (without reading the comments) would not solve the problem...

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your function  always return false : this prevents the event from being processed.

You should return **true** `if (conf)` and return **false** otherwise.

```
jQuery('.delete-row').click(function () {
    var conf = confirm('Continue delete?');
    if (conf) { 
       jQuery(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(function () {
            jQuery(this).remove();
       });

       return true;
    }
    // else...
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think he needs to throw an `else` in there.

Comment: no, since `return` stops the execution of the function at that point. It is easier to read the code, but not necessary.

Comment: @Zim84, agreed, it is better not to have the `else` which is just redundant.